# Wirelessly cast phone to PC monitor with DisplayPort and DVI, but no HDMI

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G phone that's about a year old.  I also have a spare HP Compaq LA2405wg monitor that I'd like to wirelessly cast my phone to so I can watch Netflix in the bedroom.  The monitor has Displayport, DVI, and VGA, but not HDMI.  All of the solutions I've seen available such as Chromecast and Anycast require HDMI and converting to Displayport reportedly will not work.

Is there a solution where I can cast my phone to the monitor?  I'm sure I'm not the only person with extra PC monitors hanging about that would make nice casting devices.